# When trying to PUT an object in my Array, this filter function is not removing the old object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, put

**The repo:** https://github.com/leongaban/api-design-node/tree/master

**My Postman collection:** https://www.getpostman.com/collections/b5a03b07836ad34b7758

## Expected:

Current "lion" characters:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Teemo",
        "pride": "LoL",
        "age": "1",
        "gender": "male"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Nasus",
        "pride": "LoL",
        "age": "10",
        "gender": "male"
    }
]
```

> PUT http://localhost:3000/lions/1

The body:

```
{
    "age": "1",
    "gender": "female",
    "name": "LuLu",
    "pride": "LoL"
}
```

Should return this new list on GET all lions:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "LuLu",
        "pride": "LoL",
        "age": "1",
        "gender": "female"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Nasus",
        "pride": "LoL",
        "age": "10",
        "gender": "male"
    }
]
```

## Results

```
[
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Nasus",
        "pride": "2",
        "age": "2",
        "gender": "female"
    },
    {
        "0": { // <-- This should not be here
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Teemo",
            "pride": "1",
            "age": "1",
            "gender": "female"
        },
        "age": "1",
        "gender": "female",
        "name": "LuLu",
        "pride": "LoL"
    }
]
```

### Full server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path')
const port = 3000

app.use(express.static('client'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

let lions = []
let id = 0

app.get('/lions', function(req, res) {
  console.log('GET lions:', lions)
  res.json(lions)
})

app.get('/lions/:id', function(req, res) {
  let lion = lions.filter((lion => lion.id === req.params.id))

  res.json(lion || {})
})

app.post('/lions', function(req, res) {
  id++
  const lion = Object.assign({ id: id.toString() }, req.body)
  lions.push(lion)

  res.json(lion)
});

app.put('/lions/:id', function(req, res) {
  const paramId = req.params.id
  const updated = req.body

  if (updated.id) {
    delete updated.id
  }

  const oldLion = lions.filter((lion => lion.id === paramId))

  if (!oldLion) {
    res.send()
  }

  const newLion = Object.assign(updated, oldLion)
  console.log('newLion', newLion)
  lions = lions.filter(lion => lion.id !== paramId)
  lions.push(newLion)

  res.json(newLion)
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`NODE RUNNING on port: ${port}`))
```

### The PUT function

```
app.put('/lions/:id', function(req, res) {
  const paramId = req.params.id
  const updated = req.body

  if (updated.id) {
    delete updated.id
  }

  // Here I find the oldLion to replace by id:
  const oldLion = lions.filter((lion => lion.id === paramId))

  if (!oldLion) {
    res.send()
  }

  // Here I create a new object for the new "lion":
  const newLion = Object.assign(updated, oldLion)
  console.log('newLion', newLion)

  // Here I filter out the old lion:
  lions = lions.filter(lion => lion.id !== paramId)

  // New lion is pushed in:
  lions.push(newLion)

  res.json(newLion)
});
```

Comment: On the `app.put()`, when you do `const oldLion = lions.filter((lion => lion.id === paramId))` you will get an array as result. I believe you want to use [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of filter there because later you are calling this: `const newLion = Object.assign(updated, oldLion)`.

Comment: That was exactly it `const oldLion = lions.find((lion => lion.id === paramId))`, I also needed to update my Object.assign to `const newLion = Object.assign({ id: oldLion.id }, updated)` like to post the answer?

Comment: Sure, I will give an answer shortly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential issue that can be on the `app.put()` method, is that when you do `const oldLion = lions.filter((lion => lion.id === paramId))` you will get an `array` as result. Check [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for more info about this. So, I believe you want to use [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of the `filter()` because later you are calling:

```
const newLion = Object.assign(updated, oldLion);
```

And, if `oldLion` is an `array`, `numeric-properties` will be added to the `updated` object, as you can see on next example:

```js
const updated = {somekey: "somevalue"};
console.log(Object.assign(updated, [{somekey: "updatedValue"}]));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

So, this is generating your unexpected structure, as you have mentioned:

```
[
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Nasus",
    "pride": "2",
    "age": "2",
    "gender": "female"
  },
  {
    "0": { // <-- This should not be here
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Teemo",
        "pride": "1",
        "age": "1",
        "gender": "female"
    },
    "age": "1",
    "gender": "female",
    "name": "LuLu",
    "pride": "LoL"
  }
]
```

## UPDATE

However, after reading your other fix commented, and understanding what you are trying to do, maybe it is better to use [Array.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and write your `put()` method like this:

```
app.put('/lions/:id', function(req, res)
{
    const paramId = req.params.id;
    const updated = req.body;

    if (updated.id)
        delete updated.id;

    // Here I find the oldLion to replace by id:
    const oldLionIdx = lions.findIndex(lion => lion.id === paramId);

    if (oldLionIdx < 0)
       res.send();

    // Here I update the object with the new "lion" properties:
    const newLion = Object.assign(lions[oldLionIdx], updated);
    console.log('newLion', newLion);

    res.json(newLion);
});
```